# Java iterator<Object> content access

Tags: java, stl, iterator

First, I must say that I learned Java at school (the basics...) and C++ at university (OOP). Soon I will write a Java project, and now I'm looking for the equivalent of STL in Java.

I'm learning to use iterators in Java, I've been looking for a way to access the content of the iterator without using the methods next(), previous() (which I've seen [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_iterator.htm)).
I mean the cast: iterator to Object, like operator * in pointers.
The code compiles when I write `(Object)obj` But I get `Java.lang.ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java equivalent to STL containers are the `Collection`, `List`, `Set`, and `Map` interfaces. The most common concrete implementations of those interfaces are `ArrayList`, `HashSet`, `TreeSet`, `HashMap`, and `TreeMap`.

Iterators are an old, uncommonly-used interface in Java. You normally will not need to work with iterators. Instead, use enhanced for loop syntax to loop over a container directly:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

for (String name: names) {
    System.out.printf("Hello %s%n!", name);
}
```

If you do use iterators, calling `next()` **is** the way to access the container's elements. Each call returns the next element in the collection. There is no other way. An iterator is not a pointer; you can't access its contents by dereferencing it or casting it or anything like that. You call `next()`.